# IdentityServer4 as WSFederation-client with .Net Core WSFederation preview2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4, ws-federation

I am trying to add an WSFederation authentication-provider to IdentityServer4.
Recently the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation Preview 2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation/2.0.0-preview2) was released and I was able to add this to a normal Asp.NetCore-Application.

But I am having a hard time adding it to the [IdentityServer4 EntityFramework-Quickstart-Example](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/8_EntityFrameworkStorage).

This is how I added the AuthenticationProvider in my Startup.cs/ConfigureServices-method:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddWsFederation("WsFederation", options =>
                {
                    options.Wtrealm = realm;
                    options.MetadataAddress = metadata;
                })
```

I got the button for WSFederation in the Frontend and I can also sign in. But after the callback I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: sub claim is missing
>   IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerAuthenticationService.AssertRequiredClaims(ClaimsPrincipal
>   principal)

I can understand where this comes from, it's [this line](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/6caba1b2bc56e63cefd28dee854297f8d8ec7fe3/src/IdentityServer4/Hosting/IdentityServerAuthenticationService.cs#L119) in the IdentityServerAuthenticationService.cs of IdentityServer4, it expects a "sub"-claim - WSFed does not return such a claim:

```
if (principal.FindFirst(JwtClaimTypes.Subject) == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("sub claim is missing");
```

As far as I can see, I can't configure this claim, although there are some tables in the quickstart-project that seem like they could be used for this, especially those 2:
[image: dbo.IdentityResources-table]
[image: dbo.IdentityClaims-table]

I already tried adding the claim I want to use instead of the subject-claim to the table, but It doesn't seem to have any influence, also I don't know how the database maps to the identity providers I add in the code. I'd be happy for any hints about the next steps or if you know of any examples it would be even better.

P.S.: There are already some questions regarding this topic, but they are all either from before the .Net Core-implementation of WSFederation was available or refer to a sample for a WSFederation-server, but not the client.

Comment: I just had the idea of implementing something like a custom Authenticationprovider that extends the WSFederation-authentication to convert the WSFed-claims (like upn) to IdentityProvider-compatible claims (like "sub") - but I am not sure if this would be the most elegant way. Trying to find out more by stepping through the source code & reading the docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @leastprivilege I implemented the following workaround to provide the sub-claim:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddWsFederation("WsFederation", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                    options.Wtrealm = realm;
                    options.MetadataAddress = metadata;
                    options.Events.OnTicketReceived += OnTicketReceived;
                })

/* some more code inbetween */

    /// <summary>
    /// Transform the UPN-claim to the sub-claim to be compatible with IdentityServer4
    /// </summary>
    private async Task OnTicketReceived(TicketReceivedContext ticketReceivedContext)
    {
        var identity = ticketReceivedContext.Principal.Identities.First();
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", ticketReceivedContext.Principal.FindFirstValue("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier")));

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a claims transformation on the claims coming back from the WS-Fed provider. Either by handling the events on the WS-Fed handler itself - or by using the "ExternalLoginCallback" pattern as used in the quickstart UI:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/release/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L203

Comment: Thanks - as the checking of the sub-claim is done before the ExternalLoginCallback gets hit it seems like the only option without forking IdentityServer is to do the transformation at the AuthenticationHandler itself as it should be hit before the ExternalLoginCallback. I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: I implemented an OnTicketReceived-Eventhandler adding a new identity with the sub-claim. I added the code at the bottom of my question - if you think this is an appropriate solution, feel free to add the code to your answer so I can mark it as resolved.

Comment: ExternalLoginCallback is not part of the IdentityServer codebase. It's in the UI. So whatever you prefer.

Comment: The time when the UI-code is hit is too late, as the verifying code from IdentityServer runs before the UI-code gets executed. That's why I can't place the transformation there. I now ran into another issue, there is only one identity allowed per principal - so adding another identity with the sub-claim doesn't work either. I couldn't find a setter for manipulating the Claims of the existing principal :/ /EDIT: It seems like I can set the Principal itself - I'll give this a try now.

Comment: Oh sorry, you're right - it enters the IdentityServer-Code at the "HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync"-call from ExternalLoginCallback. Thanks for your patience :)